# html then php then again html

Tags: php, html

In the following code, I would like to get the input, create the page, then go to the redirected page.

But instead I am getting the input, then going to the redirected page (it's skipping creating the page).

How can I achieve the first one?

```
<?php 

$newfile = $_GET['abc'];
$file = 'example.com';


if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>


<form onsubmit="location.href='http://www.example.com/file-created;">   

<form name="form" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="abc" placeholder="Type Here. . .">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
</form>
```

I tried using echo, but it was of no use (maybe I am making a mistake), and when I input something (without redirect), my url changes to `example.com?abc=[input_here]`. Why?

Comment: why the nested forms?

Comment: your onsubmit has typos anyways. you never close off your `'` string for the url.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have the `onsubmit`, it is submitting the form to the server to the same page that is currently loaded because you don't have a value for the `action=""` set.  So if all of that code was in index.php, the form will by default submit to index.php because you didn't tell it go to anywhere else.

Since you are using `method="get"`, it is going to add all the form data as a query string to the `action` (which you didn't specify, so it adds it to the current url).  So it appends `abc=(whatever input)` to your url and submits the form.

Now, when you have the `onsubmit` event in the url, instead of submitting the data to the server, it is just redirecting to that url.  Nothing is going to happen with all of the form data that was entered.  It is basically thrown away.

What you need to do is have your code submit to your server, do whatever processing you need to do, and then redirect to the url you want.

So something like:

```
<?php 
// check if "abc=(whatever)" is in the url, and if so do the copy to, otherwise skip it
if(isset($_GET["abc"])) {
    $newfile = $_GET['abc'];
    $file = 'example.com';


    if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
    } else {
        header("Location: http://yoursite.com/" . $newfile);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="abc" placeholder="Type Here. . .">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: I got the point, but how to redirect after the processing? I mean what is the code, or timer or function that I should use, which will only execute after processing only? I know "onsubmit" only (which tops 'processing' everytime) . . . @cj wurtz

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that part. I updated my answer.  You'll need to set a header that will cause a redirect.  I reversed the order of the code in my answer (how you had it originally) because the header() func needs to be called before any output (ie, the html below).